# Cancel/pause a Geoprocessing Task without rolling back?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, editing, arctoolbox, snapping

I have a Snap Geoprocessing task that is for about 57,000 points to lines. The issue is I need to restart the VM it is running on.

I have no idea how long it is going to run as it has been going for 48+ hours now. I do not want to cancel it and lose everything that has been done so far. Is there a way to cancel/pause it and save the edits that already occurred without it rolling back??

I'm fairly certain it is still running. I have a Fiber Manager extension and it is filling in a GUID as it is going, that is why it is taking long. It is also asking me to select from multiple objects once in a while, so it is not hanging, as of yet anyway.

It is an Enterprise Geodatabase 10.3.1, SQL Server 2008R2. I have tried to cancel it after a couple hours before and it rolled back.

Comment: 48+ hours to snap 57000 points seems way too long and possibly the process has hung - do you have any indication that it is still working?

Comment: Have you tried cancelling on a sample (on a different machine) to test whether it rolls everything back?  What are the features stored in?  Enterprise GDB, file GDB, shapefile etc.?